# Unable to find control id <ControlID> referenced by 'ControlToValidate' in Nested Grid

Tags: validation, gridview

I have a nested grid with has the ability to add a row in the FooterControl.  I want to be able to validate the data when the user clicks the Add button.
I am adding the RequiredFieldValidation in the RowDataBound method in the code behind.
If this Validation is not in this method everything works fine.  But adding the Validation produces the error - that it cannot find the ControlId that is referenced by the ControlToValidate.

If anyone can look at this to see where I am going wrong, I would appreciate it...
This is the nested grid markup:

```
    <div id="div<%# Eval("GroupID") %>" style="display:none">
<asp:GridView ID="GroupMemberGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="GroupMemberGridView_RowDeleting" 
     OnRowCommand="GroupMemberGridView_RowCommand" CssClass="grid" ShowFooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MemberID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="mggvLblMemberID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Member Name" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"> 
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="mggvLblMemberName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>               
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="mggvDDLMemberName" runat="server" 
                   class="chosen-single" data-placeholder="Choose member…">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active Device(s)">                   
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="mggvLblActiveDevice" runat="server" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("ActiveDevice").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>                   
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="mggvDeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" 
                    Text="Delete" CssClass="gridActionbutton"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Group Member?')" >
                </asp:Button>
            </ItemTemplate>                                     
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="mggvAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Member" Width="90%" ClientIDMode="Static"
                    CssClass="gridActionbutton" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="return Validate(this);" >
                </asp:Button>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

This is the RowDataBound event that creates the Validation

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    int tiGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(UserGroupGridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());                       
    GridView tgvGroupMember = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GroupMemberGridView");
    populateGroupMemberGrid(tgvGroupMember, tiGroupID);

    //Get the Footer controls that have the new entry data
    Control tFooterControls = CommonMethods.getFooterControls(tgvGroupMember);                
    DropDownList tddlRecipientNames = tFooterControls.FindControl("mggvDDLMemberName") as DropDownList;
    m_strXmlTableData = m_pagingClient.GetAllPossibleGroupMembers(m_strUserID, tiGroupID);
    DataTable tdtAllGroupMembers = CommonMethods.ParseXML(m_strXmlTableData);
    tddlRecipientNames.DataSource = tdtAllGroupMembers;
    tddlRecipientNames.DataTextField = tdtAllGroupMembers.Columns["MemberName"].ToString();
    tddlRecipientNames.DataValueField = tdtAllGroupMembers.Columns["MemberID"].ToString();
    tddlRecipientNames.DataBind();
    tddlRecipientNames.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));

    RequiredFieldValidator validator = new RequiredFieldValidator();
    validator.ID = "ReqValueDDLMember_" + tiGroupID.ToString();
    string id = ((DropDownList)tFooterControls.FindControl("mggvDDLMemberName")).UniqueID;
    validator.ControlToValidate = ((DropDownList) tFooterControls.FindControl("mggvDDLMemberName")).UniqueID;
    validator.EnableClientScript = true;
    validator.ErrorMessage = "Selection required.";
    validator.CssClass = "message-error-dropdown";
    validator.ValidationGroup = "DDLVal_" + tiGroupID.ToString();
    tgvGroupMember.Controls.Add(validator);

    Button tbtnAdd = tFooterControls.FindControl("mggvAddButton") as Button;
    tbtnAdd.ValidationGroup = "DDLVal_" + tiGroupID.ToString();
}
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
This is an ASP.NET web application using Master.Pages. Originally, I used .ID and got the same error.  I thought it was because the ID was not unique because there are several nested grids.  But, using the UniqueId identifies the specific nested grid in the parent grid.  Yet I get the same error.

If I create the validator in the markup, the validation works for only the first nested grid.

Why can't it find the darn control??

It seems I have tried just about everything to set the ControlToValidate to a unique ID that is specific to the DropDown control.

I believe my problem is that control IDs must be unique.  This is a nested grid with Master.Pages  In markup, assigning an ID to a FooterControl in a nested grid like 'mggvDDLMember' produces an ID of `'ct100$MainContent$UserGroupGridView$GroupMemberGridView$.....$mggvDDLMemberName'.`

Setting the ID in code behind like this:

```
ControlToValidate = 'mggvDDLMemberName'
```

throws an error that it can't find the control.

Using the uniqueID of the Control, mggvDDLMemberName is 'ct100$MainContent$UserGroupGridView$GroupMemberGridView$..$mggvDDLMemberNameThis produces the error that the ControlToValidate is outside the form tags because MainContent is the PlaceContentHolder:

```
ControlToValidate = ((DropDownList)tFooterControls.FindControl("mggvDDLMemberName")).UniqueID;
```

Trying to eliminate the 'ct100' so that the control is within the Placeholder. I try this:

```
ControlToValidate = ((Dropdown) this.Form.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("UserGroupGridView").FindControl("ct102").FindControl("GroupMemberGridView").FindControl("ctl13").FindControl("mggvDDLMemberName")).ID;
```

It throws the error that it can't find the control.
I am really at a loss as to how this can be done or if it can be done...:(
I tried client-side solutions to no avail.  I may have to look into that again.

**UPDATE**
I went back to the original design for the validators as opposed to adding them dynamically.  This is the FooterTemplate markup with the validator:

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="mggvDDLMemberName" runat="server" class="chosen-single" data-placeholder="Choose member…">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqValueDDLMemberInsert" runat="server" InitialValue="0" ControlToValidate="mggvDDLMemberName" ValidationGroup="InsertGroupMemberValidation" ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</FooterTemplate>
```

This is the Add button to start the validation:

```
<FooterTemplate>
   <asp:Button ID="mggvAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Member" Width="90%" CssClass="gridActionbutton" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="InsertGroupMemberValidation" >
   </asp:Button>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me...
It was not the IDs that needed to be unique but the ValidationGroup names.
So, I created all of the controls in the markup in the FooterTemplate.  But I did not name the ValidationGroup attribute. I did that in the code-behind.
This is the markup for the dropdown, validator, and button:

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" 
        ID="mggvDDLMemberName" 
        class="chosen-single" 
        data-placeholder="Choose member…">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" 
        ID="ReqValueDDLMemberInsert" 
        InitialValue="0"                                             
        ControlToValidate="mggvDDLMemberName" 
        ErrorMessage="Selection required." 
        CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</FooterTemplate>


<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Button runat="server" 
        ID="mggvAddButton" 
        CommandName="Add" 
        Text="Add Member" 
        Width="90%" 
        CssClass="gridActionbutton"/> 
</FooterTemplate>
```

In the RowDataBound Event, when I am binding the data to the dropdown, I name the ValidationGroup for each of the controls.

```
protected void UserGroupGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int tiGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(UserGroupGridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            GridView tgvGroupMember = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GroupMemberGridView");
            populateGroupMemberGrid(tgvGroupMember, tiGroupID);
            //Get the Footer controls 
            Control tFooterControls = CommonMethods.getFooterControls(tgvGroupMember);                
            DropDownList tddlRecipientNames = tFooterControls.FindControl("mggvDDLMemberName") as DropDownList;
            m_strXmlTableData = m_pagingClient.GetAllPossibleGroupMembers(m_strUserID, tiGroupID);
            DataTable tdtAllGroupMembers = CommonMethods.ParseXML(m_strXmlTableData);
            tddlRecipientNames.DataSource = tdtAllGroupMembers;
            tddlRecipientNames.DataTextField = tdtAllGroupMembers.Columns["MemberName"].ToString();
            tddlRecipientNames.DataValueField = tdtAllGroupMembers.Columns["MemberID"].ToString();
            tddlRecipientNames.ValidationGroup = "InsertMember" + tiGroupID.ToString();
            tddlRecipientNames.DataBind();
            tddlRecipientNames.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));//This is needed for the jquery-chosen dropdown to add data-holder text

            RequiredFieldValidator validator = (RequiredFieldValidator)tFooterControls.FindControl("ReqValueDDLMemberInsert");
            validator.ControlToValidate = ((DropDownList)tFooterControls.FindControl("mggvDDLMemberName")).GetUniqueIDRelativeTo(validator);            
            validator.ErrorMessage = "Selection required.";
            validator.CssClass = "message-error-dropdown";
            validator.ValidationGroup = "InsertMember" + tiGroupID.ToString();

            Button tbtnAdd = tFooterControls.FindControl("mggvAddButton") as Button;
            tbtnAdd.ValidationGroup = "InsertMember" + tiGroupID.ToString();
            tbtnAdd.CausesValidation = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.ErrorException(ex.Message, ex);
        Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx?use=" + m_strUserType);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else and saves them a little time.

Answer (score 3):

I am adding a new answer, to clarify once & for all what `BaseValidator.ControlToValidate` needs to be set to in *all* cases, including descendent/nested controls, as there are many questions about this. I hope this may of future use to others, as well as the current questioner.

The references I found above are incorrect/insufficient, as are posts elsewhere that state it should be set to either `Control.ID` or `Control.UniqueID`. The code which works in *all* cases uses a method added in .NET 4: `Control.GetUniqueIDRelativeTo(Control control)`. I could find no examples of usage anywhere on the web (including here in stackoverflow). Given a `BaseValidator validator` and a `Control control`, *once they have both been added into the page's control hierarchy*, the following is wanted:

```
validator.ControlToValidate = control.GetUniqueIDRelativeTo(validator);
```

The documentation for `GetUniqueIDRelativeTo` is incorrect/misleading. It states it returns "The prefixed portion of the UniqueID property of the specified control"; in fact it returns the "suffixed" portion, i.e. the portion to the *right* of the prefix, which is what the method name suggests. In effect, it returns the right-hand portion of `control.UniqueID` remaining after removing `validator.NamingContainer.UniqueID` from the left. This handles descendent/nested controls correctly.

Setting `BaseValidator.ControlToValidate` to `Control.ID` or `Control.UniqueID` are just degenerate cases of the above, which work in special situations (and `GetUniqueIDRelativeTo()` returns the same result anyway). If (and only if) the validator and control are in the *same* **NamingContainer** then `Control.ID` works; if (and only if) the validator's **NamingContainer** is the **Page** then `Control.UniqueID` works. Neither works in other nested/descendent situations.

Significantly, if the control's **NamingContainer** is *not* the same as or descendent from the validator's **NamingContainer** then `control.GetUniqueIDRelativeTo(validator)` goes `throw new InvalidOperationException("This control is not a descendent of the NamingContainer of '<validator>'")`. This is the cause of the error you end up when ASP.NET generates the error about not being able to locate the control to validate. In this case you are going to need to sort it out before the page will work, either by moving the validator to where the control is or up to the top page level.

For the original questioner: Neither `ID` nor `UniqueID` were correct for her original code, as per above. I think she has solved it at the end by moving the validator from a separate location/NamingContainer into the same location/NamingContainer as the DropDownList control, and hence is able to get away with `ID` degenerate case now.

Comment: My problem is not solved.  The validation does not work for my child grid after I creation of the RequiredFieldValidator from the RowCommand event.  But I will try adding back this code to the RowCommand event and use the GetUniqueIDRelativeTo() method to see if it will work.

Comment: I was called away to work on another project so I could thoroughly try the above solution.  I have tried all permutations and the validation control in the footer control in the nested grid it still does not work.  The value of the method GetUniqueIDRelativeTo() is just the ID of the dropdown.  It is not uniquely identified.

Answer (score 0):

I am working through something like this myself.  As I understand it (e.g.http://forums.asp.net/t/952691.aspx?Problem+in+Custom+Control+Unable+to+find+Control+To+Validate+Property+) the validator's `ControlToValidate` must *either* be set to the control's `ID` *provided* it is placed in the same **NamingContainer** as the control *or* can be set to the control's `UniqueID` *provided* the validator is placed in the actual **Page**.
[**EDIT**: *This paragraph and the links' explanation is inadequate/incomplete; see my new separate post below for correct discussion and solution.*]

I think each row in grids/repeaters is its own NamingContainer.  Anyway, if you try (sticking with `UniqueID`) adding the validator into the **Page** level (be careful that `validator.ID` must then itself be unique, or don't set it?), does that now make your situation work?  I'd be intested to know....

P.S.
Or, to use control's `ID` for `ControlToValidate` you must add the validator right next to the control, i.e. add it into your DropDownList's **Parent**'s control collection instead of where you are putting it?

Comment: It seems that my error does not support the information in the above link.  In my case, the NamingContainer is the Footer Row of the nested grid. The Dropdown list is the control to be validated and the ControlToValidate is set to this DDL control ID.  The 'Add' button, also within the footer row triggers the validation.  The attributes of this button for validation are set. This works for the parent grid.  However, in the child grid, when validation takes place, (ie Add button clicked) all of the DDL controls are validated for all child grids. So it is acting like a Page level validator.

Comment: I need it to act like a NamingContainer validator.  But I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Where are you physically adding the validator control in relation to the dropdown list control it is validating?  If you can add it as a sibling, then (supposedly) you can refer to it by plain `ID` instead of `UnqueID`.

Comment: I have added the markup code above to show where I set the validator.  Yes.  It is validating the control.  The problem is when you click the 'Add' button in one of the child grids it is checking **all** of the child grids, not just the one you are adding to.  So, when i expand the other child grids, the error message is showing because a selection is required.  But I don't want the validator to check all of the child grids.  Just the one that I am adding to.